# Como inserir dados de um formulário feito em Angular2 em um Banco de Dados?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, aplicação-web, angular

Estou começando a aprender Angular 2, e tenho que fazer um CRUD de um sistema sobre séries, e preciso armazenar dados em um banco de dados, atualmente, sei utilizar MySQL utilizando Xampp.

Preciso fazer a requisição utilizando Ajax. Abaixo, segue a função que pretende chamar o arquivo PHP:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo, o arquivo 'cadastrarSerie.php':

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou testando a função da primeira imagem utilizando `ng serve`para ativar o servidor HTTP para o Angular, mas o arquivo PHP não funciona, creio que seja por falta de um servidor de MySQL semelhante aquele que o Xampp ativa, pois sei que o Angular é Client-side, e PHP server-side.

1- Como posso fazer a conexão com o banco?

2- Como posso "chamar" o server-side?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Normalmente se chama o server side através de requisições http.

Comment: Sim, porém não estava conseguindo fazer isso, descobri como fazer funcionar, compilando o código angular 2 e executando dentro do xampp, logo mais postarei como resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução para esse problema utilizando xampp é:

1. Colocar todos os arquivos PHP na pasta htdocs do xampp.
2. Desenvolver a aplicação Web e utilizar o comando `ng build` para compilar o sistema.
3. Pegar a pasta 'dist' que foi criada dentro do projeto e copiá-la para a pasta htdocs.
4. Abrir o xampp, ligar servidor Apache e se necessário MySQL.
5. Acessar a aplicação.